# ADB keeps disconnecting while running android app

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, logcat, disconnect

I am developing an android app in IntelliJ 14, this shouldn't matter because I have already debugged the issue to remain outside IntelliJ. If I run "adb logcat" while I have a device attached, I will see its log output for awhile. But as soon as I run an app I am developing, the adb logcat disconnects after a little while, it is not immediate. It gets even worse when inside IntelliJ, it constantly connects/disconnects. I cannot attach the debugger or leave it attached for awhile. Sometimes i even get adb refused command. I have tried to kill/start the adb server numerous times and it is getting me nowhere. I am not sure what else to try or not even sure what would cause this issue. I cannot debug my app at all because of this. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I had similiar problem due to corrupted cable.

Comment: Thanks i will try another cable, not sure if thats it or not, this cable is new, it came with the android tablet i have. At least its something to try.

Comment: make sure you don't have multiple `adb` binaries (potentially of different versions) installed in your system

Comment: Have tried restart your computer and device?

Comment: I think in your app your are enabling and disabling WiFi in startup. So, ADB keeps disconnecting while running android app

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be the cable, wow, there was no indication that it would be that anywhere. I literally tried everything on the internet. Thank you Mikhail.